# How am I able to use multiple operating system images within Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm currently using Docker to deploy a development version of a web application. This is the **docker-compose.yml** file I wrote

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/acme.com
      - ./docker/nginx/acme.com.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/acme.com.conf
    networks:
      - my_network

  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/acme.com
    networks:
      - my_network

  database:
    build:
      context: ./docker/database
    volumes:
      - ./docker/database/acme.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/acme.sql
      - ./docker/database/remote_access.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/remote_access.sql
      - ./docker/database/custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${db_database}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${db_password}
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Looking more closely at the different context files for nginx and mysql are as follows:

**./docker/nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
```

**./docker/database/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mariadb:latest
```

So it is evident that **nginx** image uses the alpine base image.

But what image is **mariadb** using? I went through the dockerhub website and followed the link to https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/db55d2702dfc0102364a29ab00334b6a02085ef9/10.7/Dockerfile

In this file, there is a reference to

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
```

Does this mean that my docker container is using the alpine linux base image as well as the ubuntu  image? How does it work if I have multiple linux distributions in my container?

What should I do to fix this?
Should I rather install mariadb using a FROM command into alpine linux and build my own docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine your docker compose as a server farm. Each service (nginx, mariadb, ..) would be a physical server running an OS and its software. They are all connected via LAN within the same subnet. Each machine has its own IP address and there is a DNS and DHCP service running for giving the IPs and resolving names (service name = DNS-Alias). And there is a router blocking all connections from other subnets (= your host). Exceptions are configured by port mapping (=forwarding) `ports: - 8000:8000`.

So you can mix servers with all different OS variants of **one type**. This is due to the fact that docker is not a real virtual machine but more a VM light using the host OS resources to run the containers. So you can mix all kind of Linux distributions **OR** Windows versions. Every container uses the OS suiting it goals the best, e.g. Alpine for very small footprint and Ubuntu for much more comfort.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Best one so far. So, if each image is like a separate system running in the subnet, I could be running alpine for nginx, ubuntu for mariadb etc, mysql from debian:buster-slim Isn't that ineffective? Can I use alpine images for all my services? How do i specifically search for this?

Comment: Also, what is the performance impact to installing mysql, nginx on an ubuntu base image using apt-get compared to using these individual images and their own base images?

Comment: Basically you could build all your images by yourself. Nearly all `dockerfile`s of pre-built images you'll find on github. But then **you** have to care for updates, security stuff, configuration, optimization and so on. People building those images spending countless hours in bringing them to perfection. Depending on distro (especially alpine) it'll be a work out of hell and nearly impossible for mortal people. Docker does not care if you are running 10x ubuntu or 10 different distros. It is all separately, so no benefit for most use cases beside storage consumption for the image layers.